# Стоит ли объявлять constexpr-переменные static?

Tags: c++, static, constexpr

Существуют ли ситуации, когда локальные `constexpr` переменные имеет смысл объявить без ключевого слова `static`?

Т.е. есть ли смысл объявлять так:

```
void foo() {
  constexpr auto x = 42;
```

а не так:

```
void foo() {
  static constexpr auto x = 42;
```

[Пример, когда со static gcc генерит лучше код.](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%2BTXRMiAZVQtGIHgBYBQogFUAztgAKAD24AGfgCsp5eiyahUAUgBMAIUtXyKxqiIEh1ZpgDC6egFc2TEAtydwAZAiZsADk/ACNsUkCAVnIAB3QlYhcmL19/QNT0zKEwiOi2OISLZIdsJyyRIhZSIhy/AKCauqEGpqISqNj4pPtG5ta8jtG%2B8IHyoaqASnt0H1JUTi5LAGZw1F8cAGozLY8XJSJSbHZj3DMtAEE7%2B4A3dAJMA6xSAH0fFQgMExzgcWD4SAAqBbHGwPJ6A87YZ4SEFg9AHDBsFIMbDfIgATxSOPCmQkBAAXvEIAsjgB2GH3A6Mg6XIirJgHaQWaFPMw0gAiPIer3eB0E6ABQmBoJIBwI1N59KZ6MlRGw6hSpBRMvURy2fOVmOxuIJRKYJPo5MpUK2iqZTyVX1%2B/0sADZ1Nb6famQQaAcIARdbgDlp5XSvUrGWL/QcALQHHge8O0gWw/mC%2B7hIgHNgscJU2m2xmZ5k%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%2BgGHYhgWSZKlGAZxgmG12q1W4pkOGbCNmuZMDVYbzrKL3LhOq7VjOA7NV9TYtqgbZxVsQa/eW/3Tv22VfaO46w5Wa6A5uF2LhAMOTgD/b7duu77oeb6nueolWNet7rA%2BWwWPwr78QsSxIFcOAJFShjcMh5CoehmH8NhuH4YRzOft%2Bf4AcBoHgZB0FwQh3BbKT/HkzhYs6MRiAQGR6CGowFBUBKBtDMAuk8AIDBTnhEAxGTMThE0eJMfwGIcMIADyTD0C7as4DmJiSP7BCXHUzzYHhatqrUYIbM%2BmYSWTFoxL2pB4l4OBkxc5au0sNBGMASgAGoENgADunuEkezHyGxkicSxigqBoZP6JbQmmJThgEDEeGQEs6ApID3Axk2M3mNYtgWFosaeyrdm1FJEDuB5ltKaUzkGPpWnWTpBSaVkPmqZb5kOe5e8GGf3SOcpW%2Bn1Ma9edMm%2B%2BVISw3oFHEvpc8c7tzXADwYTJthdQsEXQxhdNIA4wBUAjV0r%2BHgfoLxTzEgcSiJBNTbEtgcLwpssGPgTIzIirN2ZDC5l%2BJ8iCtCPhdBYGeoELDSB/ErJCqssLcBFgRJmWtyAkWQGgfW80jbUDmtiBI5sLCWzojbag9s1aO1YOnV25B3bMCIN7X2ZMA7GGAMHE8hAw7OAjlHE8MdUBxxUYnRCJ4U5pwzlgDYJ4c6oV4P/AuLAi6lwrlXZgKim71w4rIJuPFW5q30EETuIlUF2BTv3LmQ8R5cDHkQTAE9KYzzngva%2BAQV4ySfhvWYJ8D4GSfjvI%2Bd836nwkkvc%2BVlcj7xyZZF%2BRSTLPyfucXox8TIfxppwII0U/7E0AewoW3AwEQKgTAuB8YLCIOQd3dBhBMF0yCLgoR4jVkLGIeLcgbMWAc2oBLCwsF/w0hpC6QCNDYKwRpDwLYgFbKIV5oLdWXDNbvgAQzYBathYfJZuQCOpAMiuGkEAA)

Если использовать какой-нибудь ресурсоёмкий инициализатор типа `std::array<double, 10000>{}`, то разница ещё более заметна. Вариант без `static` будет вызывать `memset` на 80000 байт каждый вызов функции, в то время как со `static` - ссылаться на одну запись из `.zero` памяти. [Пример](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%2BTXRMiAZVQtGIHgBYBQogFUAztgAKAD24AGfgCsp5eiyahUAUgBMAIUtXyKxqiIEh1ZpgDC6egFc2TA3cAGQImbAA5PwAjbFIQAE5yAAd0JWIXJi9ffwMUtOchELDIthi4xIdsJwyRIhZSIiy/AJ57bEcCplr6oiKI6NiE%2BzqGppzWpRHe0P7SwfiASnt0H1JUTi5LAGZQ1F8cAGozLY960hYAT2PcMy0AQW3d/ewjk5dJ0mx2a9uH%2B4A3dAETAHHwqCAYJiTA4sHwkSwANgWxxs91%2BkMm2H%2BEhhcPQBwwbCSDGwAH0iBckmTQukJAQAF6xCALI4AdlRdwOXIOnyIqyYB0mmBAIDOl2OHkwKyijHIBx4WkVWh%2B7LMrIAIijfmrNWiAUCQYJ0BChNDYSQDgQWWqOdyCaaiNh1ElSLiLepXur7USSeTKdSmLT6Aymcitrbub87WDsBB1GGOTrtfdQkQDmwWKFmWyI1zUzyfMICBxScRYixOkotfc7UKRahQq8bltcAWiyWy%2BdK9W/pzuUaIKRC84O46uxklAmo/30Mah%2B3qWOKxOp2iNVwlvRuABWfgBLg6cjobgeWy2QUrNYvbZ8chEbQbpYAaxA0i0ADppDx4vFpKzt1oCLbgiPAIgAHLIW5cNI/BsCAAHkPuh7Hlw/BKCAWh3g%2BSxwLAKAYDg%2BDEGQlDUHQjCsBw3C3oIwhiBInAyHIwjKGomgHnoIAWIYximGe1htB0GRuEwnjeM08HkMEMwlGUUjcXk6RCGMATbskqRKUwfSyYMPDcZU1RCN0oziTkakGZ0xnTMUAxxHpww9CpkmTD02m2fJSxKJe6zcI8TB7D4hwSmKVwttqFg7P5zyvB47xEJ83xhXqdyAsCoLghiabmugiKrr2mVYji2XesSjB%2BlSpaBs4dKMqQ2Y2tOXK8vygpEMKoqkOcoWStKsrykqyphaqGo9kmyWpYas4mlCWV4pa1qqjW3Iuc4qD2jNToum6%2BIescXqEqVZIUhVNLVcGtXMj2dqNelsbxqNI3JfmGZZgtuaWsIbYjou5bduGN11mgjY/C2X3Fj946mqNS1cgO87faWS6Vnldpw8O4OI79K4PeqG6GDue4PkeJ78VYF6rOsRwRRY/D3hxCxLEgXw4HEzL49BsHwZhSH8ChaEYVh9PPq%2BH5fj%2Bf4AUBIHgZB3BbITHHE6hgs6DhiAQPh6A%2BowFBUCa2uDMAemtORY7oRAURE1EoT1Bc1H8ISHDCAA8kw9B24rOAZiYkiewQnzVP82DoYrTpVHCGy3qm7RE8GUTnKQFxeDgRPxcW9tLDQRjAEoABqBDYAA7s7VL7jR8j0ZITG0YoKgaET%2BitEYJhoKThgEFE6GQEs6BJJW3AALRCnt5jWLYFhaAcA/O/LglVJ0IlidkLRSaJblzHZ6n5BkTmtIpnTr3JEztPPNRTLvc%2BGV0UyH7pDkmcvBguQ0t92Z53mMXenyR3jUG7ohRMULqDAgiAeCJpAHGAKgNael3w8AOBAU8Y8BIHCIiQV0N45ReANhgiKPAFi02wozZmgw2Yvi2DwOBWgIoIgsBPP8FhpBvllhzABis%2Bb2AFnTVW5BcLIDQFrQ6utqAHRJHEI2FgTYMDNtQS2itrasETvbcgjtmBEFdu7ImXteK%2B0PIQAOzgg4h0PGHVAEdlHRygoeOOCck5YA2IeNOcFeB4yziwHO%2Bci4l2YMomuldGKyBrqxeuit9DcWbnxZBdg45dzZr3fuXAh5tRHqTCeU8Z5oRPlfReF9pI2Q3rkDSnQL77wyK/J%2BWTLLn1MivCyZ9XIyXchMapj9mkNPyUfd%2BFNODcXitgH%2Bm4CZsOQtwYBoDwGQOgfKCwcCEFIJsCgtBZAqZbG4gcbBQiVkWAISrR85AmYsBZtQYWFgwKflZKyBE8RqFgTAqyHgWx4j2SgjBYZvNuD80wtwvZUEaZvKVoQoW5Ag6kDSK4aQQA%3D).

Comment: Ээээ... а зачем их объявлять как `static`?

Comment: @Harry если используем в функции адрес `x`, то без `static` инициализация будет происходить при всех вызовах функции, а не только при первом

Comment: Какая вообще инициализация `constexpr` при живом оптимизаторе? :) Скорее всего и память под такую переменную выделена не будет. Так что скорее `static` — для какой-то исключительной ситуации, когда эта переменная должна выходить за рамки функции, но передавать адрес жесточайшей, известной еще во время компиляции константы? Зачем?

Comment: @Harry добавил пример, когда без `static` gcc не смог заинлайнить код

Comment: Так это и есть -- *использование адреса* `odr_use(&x);`, т.е. выделение места в памяти, все в рамках описанного.  Выбросьте этот вызов и убедитесь, что код будет одинаковым... А теперь — вы пишете, что обычно нужен `static` — т.е. вы считаете такое использование  *адреса* `constexpr` — *обычным и распространенным*?...

Comment: @Harry добавил пример, который можно считать распространённым. Я говорю не про необходимость `static`, а про то, что с ним более производительный код в некоторых случаях, но не менее производительный во всех, т.е. нет смысла его не использовать

Comment: Раз вы уже поняли ответ, его стоит запостить отдельным "ответом" ниже, и поставить рядом галочку, чтобы отметить вопрос решенным...

Answer (score 1):

Например, если вы берете адрес переменной (или ссылку) и переедаете ее за пределы функции, поведение отличается принципиально. Хотя это странный способ использования `constexpr`, но разрешенный стандартом.

Если адрес переменной `x` никак не используется, то в режиме оптимизации, компиляторы сгенерирую один и тоже код, в котором память под x не будет выделена ни на стеке, ни в сегменте констант.

Comment: Так вот именно, в этом случае `static` лучше, т.к. инициализация 1 раз будет происходить. Есть ли случаи когда без `static` лучше?

Comment: Да всегда лучше, кроме вот таких вот удивительных с точки зрения здравого смысла ситуаций. Imho, конечно...

Comment: @john, что значит, что инициализация будет один раз происходить? Она ж при компиляции происходит?

Comment: @Qwertiy выражение справа от `=` будет вычислено на этапе компиляции, а копирование его в переменную без `static` будет происходит при каждом вызове функции; и первое вроде бы даже не гарантировано без `static`

Comment: @john это только если вы отдали адрес переменной за пределы функции, как в вашем примере. Но зачем constexpr переменную передавать не по значению? Если в дочерней функции используется адрес, а не значение по адресу, то такие функции имеют разное поведение., и вопрос "что лучше" - неприменим.

Comment: @Chorkov если нужен сам адрес - согласен, нет однозначно лучшего результата

Comment: @Chorkov по константной ссылке вполне может быть передача, а не по значению. В этом случае тоже со `static` код лучше

Comment: @john Именно поэтому я написал про передачу по значению.

Comment: @Chorkov "Но зачем constexpr переменную передавать не по значению?" - вполне часто передают переменные в функции по константным ссылкам, а не по значению, независимо от того, была она `constexpr` или нет. То есть по умолчанию стоит использовать `static`, если нет манипуляций с адресом, я про это

Answer (score 1):

Понятие лучше - понятие относительное. Если вы объявляете переменную со `static`, то получается переменная с глобальным временем жизни и локальной областью видимости. А без `static` - переменная с локальными временем жизни и областью видимости.
А `constexpr` - не панацея, потому что компилятор считает, что всегда в коде может встретиться `const_cast<>`. Опять-таки, в `c/c++` - константность скорее возможность компилятора помочь программисту избежать ошибок.
Здесь скорее нужно выбирать, в какой переменной вы нуждаетесь, исходя из логики вашей программы.

Comment: В случае локальной `constexpr` переменной по моему мнению лучше объявить её с `static`, т.к. существуют ситуации, где это сгенерит лучший код. Смысл вопроса в том, чтобы найти ситуации, когда код будет хуже. Если таких нет, то в вопросе производительности первое однозначно лучше второго в любой программе. Про `const_cast` не понял; думаю, что он никак не влияет на восприятие `constexpr` компилятором

Comment: Влияет на оптимизатор. Смотрел много выступлений - константность не используется для оптимизаций. И скорее всего вы получите с `static` - переменную с глобальным временем жизни, и в зависимости от остального кода, она может быть создана даже не на стеке. Без `static` - это переменная с локальным временем жизни.

Comment: Не знаю, что за выступления говорят, что константность не используется для оптимизаций, но вот пример выступления, где говорится обратное https://youtu.be/uzF4u9KgUWI?t=468